# What does "allocated inline in a structure" mean for Value-Types?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, value-type

From MSDN it says "[Value types are allocated on the stack or inline.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)"

Does "allocated inline" mean that value type can be allocated right after where it is declared? Say if it is declared in a Heap, then it is allocated in the next Heap slot?

Then why does it say "in a structure"?

#### Update

if the "structure" specifically means "struct", why it doesn't mention anything regarding "class"? as a field in a `Class`, it is not on the stack, nor inline in a `struct`, (it is inline in a `class`).

Comment: Even for allocated heap memory, a fixed amount is allocated. The value-types (for value-typed members) live in this allocated memory vs. being allocated in another segment. (A value-type named by an object-typed or interface-typed is allocated in another segment.)

Answer (score 3):

They are allocated inline *in a structure*, so as part of the memory already allocated to a structure.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx

If you had nested value types, the inner type would be allocated in memory already allocated for the containing type.

```
struct Inner
{
    public int A;
}

struct Outer
{
    public Inner I;
    public int B;
}

Outer o = new Outer();
o.I = new Inner();
```

Memory for `I` is allocated inline, in the memory allocated to an instance of `Outer`.

Comment: Or, indeed, as a field on a class. Not just on a structure,

Comment: @MarcGravell hmm, why then the sentence only says "on a structure", not "on a structure or a class", see my update in question

Comment: @colinfang I am probably splitting hairs - I interpret "inline" to mean "wher-ever that containing thing is", which applies equally to both. In the case of class, one could argue that it is "inline", even though always on the heap. In the case of a struct, it could ultimately be struct *or* heap.

Comment: @MarcGravell Did you mean "In the case of a struct, it could ultimately be **stack** or heap"?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think of a struct is as a group of storage locations stuck together with duct tape.  Declaring a variable or field `Point foo;` is essentially equivalent to saying `int Point_X; int Point_Y;`.  Saying `foo = bar;`, when both are of type `Point`, is essentially equivalent to saying `foo_X = bar_X; foo_Y = bar_Y;`.  Passing a struct as a value parameter is essentially equivalent to passing all its fields (public and private) as value parameters.

There are two structural and one mostly-syntactic-sugary ways in which a struct is more than a group of fields stuck together with duct tape:

1. It is possible to pass a struct as a `byref` parameter, in which case the system passes one reference to the whole group of storage locations (as distinct from passing the storage locations individually, as effectively happens when passing by value).

   Each slot of an array of a struct type will hold all its storage locations together, so `Point foo[];` is very different from `int foo_X[]; int foo_Y[];`.  The former declaration represents one array with two storage locations per element, while the latter represents two arrays with one storage location per element.

   It is possible to associated methods and properties with a struct, and to define struct fields which can only be accessed either through those methods and properties, or by performing an operation like assignment on all fields of a struct together.

Class types are very different from structs.  If one declares a class with fields P and Q, and one declares a storage location of that class type, that storage location will not hold two things (P and Q).  It will just hold one thing--a reference to an object, stored elsewhere, which itself has fields P and Q.